# Android, Java, Eclipse: Syntax Error on token "if", ( expected after this token

Tags: java, android, syntax-error

Why do i get the following Syntax error ?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences pvtPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean isFirstLaunch = pvtPref.getBoolean("isFirstLaunch", false);
    if (isFirstLaunch == true) {   // <<<< Syntax Error ?
    // Do Something
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Multiple Markers at this line
-Syntax error on token "if", ( expected after this token
-Line breakpoint:LaunchEngine[line:30] - onCreate(Bundle)
```

Comment: am not getting it.. can u just refresh the project.

Comment: Refreshed it a couple of times, Restarted Eclipse but no luck ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences pvtPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isFirstLaunch = pvtPref.getBoolean("isFirstLaunch", false);
    if (isFirstLaunch) {   // <<<< Syntax Error ?
    // Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Unfortunately using if(isFirstLaunch) also gives me the same error. I have updated the Error Messages.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

1. First see that you have declared isFirstLaunch as boolean, if you have it should work.
2. No need to use `isFirstLaunch == true`

   `if(isFirstLaunch)`

Comment: Thanks for your response, Unfortunately using if(isFirstLaunch) also gives me the same error. I have updated the Error Messages.

Comment: I just tried your code in my Android program, it worked with no errors.. I think the problem is outside the onCreate(), are you trying to do some operation outside the onCreate() method, i mean u can only declare variables etc in the class scope, everything else is in method scope..pls check

Comment: Dunno what is wrong, i am getting syntax errors for no reason, maybe something's wrong with eclipse, same code works fine in windows

Comment: Can you pls paste the entire code over here, so i check it with my eclipse once again...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a Boolean instead of a boolean. So you should use either :

```
Boolean isFirstLaunch = pvtPref.getBoolean("isFirstLaunch", false);
if (isFirstLaunch.booleanValue()) {   
}
```

or :

```
boolean isFirstLaunch = pvtPref.getBoolean("isFirstLaunch", false);
if (isFirstLaunch) {   
}
```

And try to click on the error icon on the left, and choose "Clear all lint marker" (if it's there).

Answer (score 0):

This is the error that you get if you don’t have a Boolean value in the `if` condition or if you are comparing some different types, like `("java" > 0)`.